# Fat ViewModels for editing images

Tags: c#, image, mvvm

How should I deal with `ViewModel`s that are "fat"? Or should I just accept it sometimes.

Example - one of my `ViewModel`s (editing image page, almost 300 lines of code) which has a lot of UI commands like cropping, quick image filters (like contrast, brightness), undo, redo etc.

```
public class ImageEditViewModelWinRt : Shared.ViewModel.ImageEditViewModel
{
    private readonly FilterStorage _filterStorage;

    public ImageEditViewModelWinRt(FilterStorage filterStorage, ViewServices viewServices) 
        : base(viewServices)
    {
        IsFadeInAnimationEnabled = true;
        _filterStorage = filterStorage;
        QuickFix = new QuickImageFixProperties();
        InitializeCommands();
    }

    private void InitializeCommands()
    {
        AddFilterCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            string addFilterKey = ViewServices.ResourceDictionary.ImageEditPageDictionaryKeys.AddFilterPageKey;
            NavigateTo(addFilterKey, FilteredImage);
        }, () => !IsOperationInProgress);

        UndoCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await TryRunAsyncOperation(UndoChangesExecute), () => !IsOperationInProgress);
        RedoCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await TryRunAsyncOperation(RedoChangesExecute), () => !IsOperationInProgress);
        SaveChanges = new RelayCommand(async () => await TryRunAsyncOperation(SaveChangesToCurrentFileExecute), () => !IsOperationInProgress);
        SaveChangesToPickedFile = new RelayCommand(async () => await TryRunAsyncOperation(SaveChangesToPickedFileExecute), () => !IsOperationInProgress);
        CancelEditing = new RelayCommand(CancelEditingExecute, () => !IsOperationInProgress);
        CropImageCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await TryRunAsyncOperation(CropImageCommandExecute), () => !IsOperationInProgress);
        RotateImageCommand = new RelayCommand<double>(async (angle) => await TryRunAsyncOperation(RotateImageCommandExecute, angle));
        FlipHorizontalImageCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await TryRunAsyncOperation(FlipHorizontalImageCommandExecute));
        FlipVerticalImageCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await TryRunAsyncOperation(FlipVerticalImageCommandExecute));
        ImageQuickFixCommand = new RelayCommand(async () =>
        {
            IsFadeInAnimationEnabled = false; // in case of QuickFix preview looks ugly with fade animation
            QuickFix.EnqueueCurrentFilter();
            await TryRunAsyncOperation(ImageQuickFixCommandExecute);
            IsFadeInAnimationEnabled = true;
        });
    }

    [SetCurrentOperationUserFriendlyMessageAspect(UserFriendlyMessage = "Undo operation is in progress...", IsCancellable = false)]
    private async Task UndoChangesExecute()
    {
        if (_filterStorage.Undo())
            await RefreshImageProvider();
    }

    [SetCurrentOperationUserFriendlyMessageAspect(UserFriendlyMessage = "Redo operation is in progress...", IsCancellable = false)]
    private async Task RedoChangesExecute()
    {
        if (_filterStorage.Redo())
            await RefreshImageProvider();
    }

    [SetCurrentOperationUserFriendlyMessageAspect(UserFriendlyMessage = "Cropping image is in progress...", IsCancellable = false)]
    private async Task CropImageCommandExecute()
    {
        _filterStorage.AddFilter(new ImageCroppingFilter(SelectedCroppingArea));
        await RefreshImageProvider();
    }

    [SetCurrentOperationUserFriendlyMessageAspect(UserFriendlyMessage = "Rotating image is in progress...", IsCancellable = false)]
    private async Task RotateImageCommandExecute(double angle)
    {
        _filterStorage.AddFilter(new RotateFilter(angle));
        await RefreshImageProvider();
    }

    [SetCurrentOperationUserFriendlyMessageAspect(UserFriendlyMessage = "Flipping image is in progress...", IsCancellable = false)]
    private async Task FlipHorizontalImageCommandExecute()
    {
        _filterStorage.AddFilter(new FlipImageFilter(FlipMode.Horizontal));
        await RefreshImageProvider();
    }

    [SetCurrentOperationUserFriendlyMessageAspect(UserFriendlyMessage = "Flipping image is in progress...", IsCancellable = false)]
    private async Task FlipVerticalImageCommandExecute()
    {
        _filterStorage.AddFilter(new FlipImageFilter(FlipMode.Vertical));
        await RefreshImageProvider();
    }

    [SetCurrentOperationUserFriendlyMessageAspect(UserFriendlyMessage = "Quick fix is in progress...", IsCancellable = false)]
    private async Task ImageQuickFixCommandExecute()
    {
        bool hasImageBeenRefreshed = true;

        while (QuickFix.IsQuickFixAvailable() && hasImageBeenRefreshed)
        {
            _filterStorage.AddOrModifyFilter(QuickFix.DequeueFilter());
            hasImageBeenRefreshed = await RefreshImageProvider();
        }
    }

    [SetCurrentOperationUserFriendlyMessageAspect(UserFriendlyMessage = "Saving changes in progress...")]
    private async Task SaveChangesToCurrentFileExecute()
    {
        await SaveImageChanges(FilteredImage.FolderImage.ImageFile);
    }

    [SetCurrentOperationUserFriendlyMessageAspect(UserFriendlyMessage = "Saving changes to new file...")]
    private async Task SaveChangesToPickedFileExecute()
    {
        var savePicker = new FileSavePicker() { SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary };
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".jpg", new[] { ".jpg" });
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".png", new[] { ".png" });

        var fileToSave = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (fileToSave != null)
            await SaveImageChanges(fileToSave);
    }

    private async Task SaveImageChanges(StorageFile toFile)
    {
        string errorMsg = "";
        string errorTitle = "";

        try
        {
            IImageSaver imageSaver = FilteredImage.GetFilteredImageSaver(toFile);
            await imageSaver.SaveImage(FilteredImage.FolderImage.ImageFile, CancellationToken);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            errorMsg = "Image which you're trying to save was probably deleted in the meantime ;(\n" +
                       "You'll be transfered to the main page.";
            errorTitle = "Image couldn't be saved ;-(";
        }
        catch (InvalidImageFileException)
        {
            errorMsg = "The image you're trying to save is not valid image file. Can't do that ;(\n" +
                       "You'll be transfered to the main page.";
            errorTitle = "Image couldn't be saved ;-(";
        }
        catch (ImageDimensionsTooSmallException)
        {
            errorMsg = "Sorry you can't save that image.\nMinimal image dimension is 30 px width and 30 px height.";
            errorTitle = "Image couldn't be saved ;-(";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorTitle))
            await ShowMessageAndNavigateToMainPage(errorMsg, errorTitle);

    }

    [NavigateBackOnExitAspect]
    private void CancelEditingExecute()
    {
        _filterStorage.Clear();
    }

    [SetCurrentOperationUserFriendlyMessageAspect(UserFriendlyMessage = "Loading data is in progress.", IsCancellable = false)]
    [StoreImageFileInRecentlyUsedListAspect(ApplyToStateMachine = true)]
    public async Task LoadData(FolderImage folderImage)
    {
        string errorTitle = "";
        string errorMsg = "";

        try
        {
            await TryRunAsyncOperation(async () =>
            {
                CurrentFilters = _filterStorage.Filters;
                FilteredImage = new FilteredImageFileModel(folderImage, CurrentFilters);
                FilteredImageProvider = FilteredImage.GetFilteredImage();
                await FilteredImageProvider.Load();
            });
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            errorTitle = "Can't load edit page chief ;-(";
            errorMsg =
                "The image you're trying to edit is no longer available - perhaps it was removed in the meantime. \n" +
                "You'll be transfered to the main page.";
        }
        catch (InvalidImageFileException)
        {
            errorTitle = "Can't load edit page chief ;-(";
            errorMsg = "The image you're trying to edit is not a valid image file.";
        }
        catch (ImageDimensionsTooSmallException)
        {
            errorMsg = "Sorry you can't edit this image.\nMinimal image dimension is 30 px width and 30 px height.";
            errorTitle = "Can't load edit page chief ;-(";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorTitle))
            await ShowMessageAndNavigateToMainPage(errorMsg, errorTitle);
    }

    private async Task<bool> RefreshImageProvider()
    {
        string errorMsg = "";
        string errorTitle = "";

        try
        {
            await FilteredImageProvider.InvalidateImage();
            CurrentFilters = new List<Filter>(_filterStorage.Filters);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            errorTitle = "Can't render image :(";
            errorMsg =
                "The image which you're editing is no longer available - perhaps it was removed in the meantime. \n" +
                "You'll be transfered to the main page.";
        }
        catch (InvalidImageFileException)
        {
            errorTitle = "Can't render image :(";
            errorMsg = "The image you're trying to edit is not a valid image file.";
        }
        catch (ImageDimensionsTooSmallException)
        {
            errorMsg = "Sorry you can't edit this image.\nMinimal image dimension is 30 px width and 30 px height.";
            errorTitle = "Can't render image :(";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorTitle))
        {
            await ShowMessageAndNavigateToMainPage(errorMsg, errorTitle);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private async Task ShowMessageAndNavigateToMainPage(string message, string title, bool preservePageInNavigationStack = false)
    {
        await ViewServices.MessageService.ShowMessage(title, message);
        _filterStorage.Clear();
        NavigateToMainPageCommand.Execute(null);

        if (!preservePageInNavigationStack)
            ViewServices.NavigationService.PopRecentFrame();
    }

    public IImageSourceProvider FilteredImageProvider { get; private set; }
    public FilteredImageFileModel FilteredImage { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Filter> CurrentFilters { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CropImageCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand<double> RotateImageCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand FlipHorizontalImageCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand FlipVerticalImageCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand ImageQuickFixCommand { get; private set; }
    public QuickImageFixProperties QuickFix { get; private set; }
    public Rect SelectedCroppingArea { get; set; }
    public Rect ImageBounds { get; set; }
    public bool IsFadeInAnimationEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Most of the code is pretty straight-forward (at least for me) - except for ugly exception handling (I'd go for aspects there but with current postsharp async support it is not possible). Is there any universal solution for a "lot of commands" view models?

Comment: is this problem still exist? or have you got any way to solve it

Comment: what about splitting the this view model up into a few smaller view models with different responsibilities. For example, undo / redo and image manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When faced with a class you think is too large, it's best to apply the Single Responsibility Principle. So let's give it a go.

What is this class called? `ImageEditViewModelWinRt`

From this, I draw the assumptions that it is the WinRt version of a view model tailored to image manipulation. As such, this class should only contain image manipulation view model logic.

What does the class do? I did a quick tally and it appears to have the following functionality:

- Undo / Redo / Cancel changes
- Saving / Loading
- Cropping / Rotating
- Quick fix (whatever that is, I'm guessing an auto-rotate, but maybe it plays with colours and levels, etc?)

So it looks like this could be split into three (maybe four) `ViewModel`s. That ought to be a great start. For communicating between the `ViewModel`s I recommend using a messenger or dependency injection to keep coupling loose, although for things like a save/load `ViewModel` or an Undo/Redo `ViewModel` inheritance is probably a wise bet.

As for other aspects of your code (which mostly seem great to me):

```
bool hasImageBeenRefreshed = true;
```

Prefer to use `var` for local declarations when the right-hand side makes the type obvious. This is really helpful when you decide to change something's type later. You actually do this a lot, but not all the time.

```
string errorMsg = "";
```

Again a candidate for `var`, but also prefer to use `string.Empty` over `""` because it gets your intent across better, and can't be confused with `" "` when skim-reading.

Lastly I really don't like underscore notation, I find it a strong detractor of readability, but that's a matter of personal preference.